# neither socket option "SO_DONTROUTE" nor send() flags "MSG_DONTROUTE" works

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

as my understanding from man page, when MSG_DONTROUTE is set, the packet should only be sent to a destination directly connected to the source. 
However, when I try to send a packet to a indirect connected destination (routing required), the send() still returns a positive value back. Do I misunderstand anything, thanks?

## Here's my testing code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    const char* ip = argv[1] ? argv[1] : "74.125.31.100"; // google

    int fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd == -1)
        ErrAndExit("socket");

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset (&addr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons (80);
    if (inet_pton (AF_INET, ip, &addr.sin_addr) != 1)
        ErrAndExit ("inet_pton");

    if (connect (fd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
        ErrAndExit("connect");

    // int optval = 1;
    // int optlen = sizeof(optval);
    // if (setsockopt (fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DONTROUTE, (void*) &optval, optlen) == -1)
    //     ErrAndExit ("setsockopt");

    ssize_t written = send (fd, "apple", 6, MSG_DONTROUTE);
    if (written == -1)
        ErrAndExit ("send");
    else
        printf ("wrote %ld bytes\n\n", written);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the time you've already established a **connection**, it's definitely too late to say you don't want routing. Off the top of my head, I suspect that flag only makes sense for connectionless protocols, but the socket option might also work for tcp as long as you set it **before** calling `connect`.